Pandera checks onle 1st condition, I want all conditions
In code:
import pandas as pd
import pandera as pa

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    "column1": [None, 2, 3, 4],
    "column2": ["A", None, "C", "D"],
    "column3": [46.0, 50.0, 30.0, 70.0],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Define the validation schema
schema = pa.DataFrameSchema({
    "column1": pa.Column(int),
    "column2": pa.Column(str),
    "column3": pa.Column(float, checks=[
        pa.Check(lambda x: x is not None, error="shouldn't be None"),
        pa.Check(lambda x: x > 45.0, error="has to be > 45.0"),
    ]),
})

try:
    schema.validate(df)
    print("Validation successful!")
except pa.errors.SchemaError as e:
    print(f"Validation failed: {e}")

    clean_df = df[~df.index.isin(e.failure_cases['index'])]
    not_clean_df = df[df.index.isin(e.failure_cases['index'])]

print('\nclean_df\n', clean_df)
print('\nnot_clean_df\n', not_clean_df)

RESULT:
Validation failed: non-nullable series 'column1' contains null values:
0   NaN
Name: column1, dtype: float64

clean_df
    column1 column2  column3
1      2.0    None     50.0
2      3.0       C     30.0
3      4.0       D     70.0

not_clean_df
    column1 column2  column3
0      NaN       A     46.0

But evidently conditions are NOT meet in every row except indx3 [4, "D", 70]. It looks that Pandera checks only first issue
Can anybody help?
I tried mayny different ways to achieve goal :)

OK, I have solution:
try:
    schema.validate(df, lazy=True)
    print("Validation successful!")
except pa.errors.SchemaErrors as e:
    print(f"Validation failed: {e}")
    failure_indices = e.failure_cases["index"].dropna().astype(int)
    print(failure_indices)
    print(e.failure_cases["index"])
    doNothing
    # Utworzenie DataFrame z poprawnymi wierszami
    df_valid = df.drop(failure_indices)
    doNothing

    # Utworzenie DataFrame z błędnymi wierszami
    df_invalid = df.loc[failure_indices]
    doNothing

